# How to display one day to the current date? Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I need to show the current date increased by one. In one case I did it but in the other, it fails when I'm shown the full name of the day instead of the date + only date with number. I will show you my code and I hope you will understand.

First I have a function that convert my date into what I want it to be my date helper.js.

```
export function Converter(date){
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const dayName = date.toLocaleDateString('hr', { weekday: 'long' })
  // dayName.setDate(dayName) + 1;
  // This is increased my day + 1 but I want on input change to set selected day.
  // example now date 1/13/2020 ... with this code is is 1/14/2020 but when select example 1/25/2020  
  // i want to show 25 but this show 26 because I set + 1
  // So I don't think I should change it here.
  const day = date.getDate() ;
  return  dayName.toUpperCase() + ' '  +  year + '-' + month + '-' + day
}
```

Now look at my ts file.

```
  startDateString: any = '';
  this.startDateString = Converter(this.startDate);

  addEvent(type: string, event: any) {
    this.startDateString = Converter(event.value._d);
    //this is work fine. Convert me date in example...
    //MONDAY 2020-1-13
  }
```

My html:

```
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
          <input (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)"  [matDatepicker]="date" [(ngModel)]="startDate" name="startDate"  matInput   placeholder="Izaberite datum isporuke"   >
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date" ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker touchUi #date></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

My question.

> How to display date `onInit` current day + 1 for date.

Example today is `Monday 1/13/2020`. 
My code show now `MONDAY 2020-1-13`.
I want to show onInit `THUESDAY 2020-1-14`.
If it's Wednesday to show Thursday.
If 15 to show 16.
This is only for Oninit.
This is for another day I am solved with:

```
this.startDate.setDate(this.startDate.getDate() + 1);
```

But in this situation with current code which I provide here i don't know how do it?

Comment: Why don't you just call `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)` in the first line of your `Converter()` function?

Comment: Hmm this is work, but am told above Now when I choose 1/25/2020 he shows me 1/26/2020. I want onInit to give me a current date + 1 but when I select 1/20/2020 or 1/26/2020 or 1/27/2020 it displays that selected date. @levininja

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I probably need to change in OnInit function..

Comment: Consider creating a plunker or so that reproduces the problem.  It's hard to understand with just a code fragment.